# Android which uses Permission for pay?

Tags: android, permissions

What permissions do I include in my app to allow users to buy, with codec promotional or phone credit? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Permission which you need. By the way read 
[tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) from Google. Also they have published sample app.